# How to calculate sample size from given data?

Tags: sampling, sample-size

I have a dataset of questions from 5 different categories C1, C2, ... C5. Let's say the number of questions from each category has a different size say N1, N2,..N5, and sizes are large. I need to manually analyze these questions' answers to have a say on criteria like whether they are accurate or not, complete or not, etc. As I can't manually analyze all the questions from all categories, I am thinking of sampling questions from each category.

Do I need to calculate a minimally statistically significant sample size for this kind of analysis? If yes, how should I calculate it?

**Edit:**

Clarification about questions in data: Suppose I collect questions and their respective answers from stats.stackexchange.com and a few other sister websites, where each sister website is a category. I want to analyze the answers to find out which ones are correct or complete with a 95% confidence level and 5% margin of error.

**Edit 2:**
I want to find out which questions are correct or complete with a 95% confidence level and 5% margin of error on a per-category basis.

Suppose my data looks like this:

| Category | Number of questions |
| --- | --- |
| C1 | 250000 |
| C2 | 40000 |
| C3 | 1500 |

I am thinking of two ways to go about this.

**First approach without stratification:**

1. Combine the list of questions from `C1, C2, ... C5` in one list of 291,500 questions.
2. Calculate the sample size for the required confidence interval and margin or error. With this example, it would be `384`.
3. Sample `384` questions from the combined list of questions from all categories.
4. Analyze the `384` sampled questions' answers.
5. Finally, to draw a conclusion on per per-category basis, break down 384 questions' analysis results into their respective categories.

**Second approach with stratification:**

1. Keep the questions stratified for each category, and calculate the sample size for each category. For the example data, that would be the following:

| Category | Number of questions | Sample size |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C1 | 250000 | 384 |
| C2 | 40000 | 381 |
| C3 | 1500 | 306 |

2. Sample the number of questions mentioned for each category from each category, in a total of `384 + 381 + 306 = 1071` questions.
3. Analyze the `1071` questions and draw conclusions on a per-category basis by using samples from their respective categories.

**Q1:** Which approach is the correct way of doing it?

**Q2:** Also, what is the downside of using the first approach as it requires less manual work?

Comment: Hi! Are the questions open ended (i.e. are respondents offered a free text field and can answer whatever they want?). Or do the questions offer a limited number of options? Do you intend to analyze all the answers to the questions you will select? Can you share a snippet of what your data look like? (you can use made-up data, it's just to get a better idea of how the dataset is structured, this is a bit difficult to understand from your description)

Comment: You don't "calculate a minimally statistical sample size" you find one that has XX% power to reject a null hypothesis at type error = XX% .  You haven't given a hypothesis. Alternatively, you calculate the sample size needed to estimate a parameter to a certain degree of accuracy. But you haven't told us any parameters.

Comment: @J-J-J Questions are open-ended.

Comment: @PeterFlom Thank you for steering me in the right direction. I have updated the question.

Comment: This sentence is lacking info: "*I want to analyze the answers to find out which ones are correct or complete with a 95% confidence level and 5% margin of error.*". Do you mean that you want to estimate the overall proportion of incorrect answers (no matter the categories)? Or the proportion of incorrect answers in each category? Or something completely different? I ask because your sentence can be also interpreted as "I want to automatically identify incorrect or incomplete answers", but from the rest of the question it doesn't seem it's what you're after. Could you clarify things a bit more?

Comment: @J-J-J I have updated the questions with more clarification.

Comment: Please remove the phrase 'statistically significant' from the title and the question. That phrase usually just leads to confusion among statistical novices.  But here it is really ambiguous as there is no such thing as a "statistically significant sample size".  Also, your edits still don't give the information @J-J-J was asking about (I have the same questions).

Comment: I want to estimate the proportion of incorrect answers on a per-category basis.